# Can we build a domain Whitelabel multi-tenancy system with S3 and cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to build a web app which is a white-labeled multi-tenant system. The codebase for the app will be the same for all the tenants. I was thinking to host the static app in the s3 bucket and create a CloudFront distribution for the same.

I am able to provision an SSL cert from AWS with a limit of 10 domains/cert and add these domains as a cname in CloudFront.

This way I am able to serve up to 10 tenants per cloudfront distribution.

This is not a scalable approach because the cname soft [limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/cloudfront-limits.html#limits-web-distributions) we have for CloudFront is 100/distribution and also I can only use one SSL cert per distribution.

I don't want to create a separate distribution for each tenant as that will be an unnecessary maintenance overload in the deployment cycles and cache invalidation for each distribution.

Is there a better serverless architecture to build a domain Whitelabel multi-tenancy system?

Comment: do you want a seperate domain name for each tenant,  myclient.com ?
would it be an option to just create seperate subdomains for each client like client1.mycompany.com ?

Comment: @BuriB I need a separate domain for each. domainA.com, domainB.com, etc

Comment: in that case I'd consider deploying a seperate stack for each customers of yours and rather solve the problem of the automation of each customer.

You also have to think about how you bill yours customers. If you have 1 CF distro, all the traffic will go to the same distro, if domainA.com has 1 visit per month and domainB.com has 200 million, how would you easily see the usage per customer ?

I'd create 1 organization in AWS ( check control tower ) and create a seperate account per customer and 1 core code account to store my s3 code. You can set up cross account s3 access.

Comment: "I don't want to create a separate distribution for each tenant as that will be an unnecessary maintenance overload in the deployment cycles" -> you'll need to automate your code anyways ( InfraStructureAsCode )

"cache invalidation for each distribution." -> if CloudFront caching is properly set up, you won't need invalidation.

Comment: @BuriB, I was planning to bill each tenant by [querying the cloudfront logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/cloudfront-logs.html) and calculate the usage based on the hostname.

Comment: "querying the cloudfront logs" -> it's also a solution but essentially you're solving the problem that AWS already solved with their 'Billing & Cost Management` service. If you separate your customers stack, you'd just need to call billing api instead of manually trying to figure out usage costs.

Comment: btw. the soft limits can be increased by opening a support ticket in your AWS account.

Comment: Thanks, @BuriB for the suggestions. I will look into the pros and cons of creating a separate account for each tenant vs creating a separate CF distribution for my specific use case.